# Facebook Like Box Responsive Options

Tags: jquery, css, facebook

I'm putting together a responsive layout using unsemantic, and I'd like to change the options on a Facebook Like box when the view switches to/from desktop/tablet/mobile.  That is, when the browser switches to a smaller layout, I want to change the options to no longer display faces or a post feed.

I'm currently loading two like boxes in and showing/hiding one depending on the browser width using css, but this can't be the most efficient way (the site is still in early development, so these are just for sketches at the moment)...

```
<div class="grid-100 tablet-grid-50 hide-on-mobile">
    <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/myurl" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false"></div>
</div>
<div class="hide-on-desktop hide-on-tablet mobile-grid-100">
    <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/myurl" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false"></div>
</div>
```

I've got jquery triggering an event whenever a breakpoint is hit, and I was thinking that I could use this to change the Like Box's options and refresh it.  I'm guessing it's possible, since the Facebook developer's page changes its layout as you configure it.

So, the question - is there any way to only have one Facebook like box and change its options using JQuery as browser size events are triggered?  And if so, would it be a better way?

(Note, obviously a change script won't be executed that much since the browser is likely to be fixed, but it might be triggered from a portrait->landscape on a tablet)

Comment: CSS media queries perhaps? http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Thanks Jay.  That's how it's working at the moment - hide-on-mobile/table/desktop are all media queries in the unsemantic css.  Just wondering whether it's possible (and advisable) to change the data attributes of a FB div and redraw it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even use jQuery, CSS is going to perform better anyway.  In your css file, put this (where ### is the width of the page in pixels when you want to hide the div):

```
@media (max-width: (###-1)px)    
{    
    div.hide-on-desktop
    {
        display:none;
    }
    div.hide-on-mobile
    {
        display:block;
    }
}

@media (min-width: ###px)    
{    
    div.hide-on-desktop
    {
        display:block;
    }
    div.hide-on-mobile
    {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The thing is, I don't want to hide the box, I want to change its options (to make it a more basic box on smaller widths).  The unsemantic css means that styles like "hide-on-mobile" are triggered with media queries.

Comment: I've never used unsemantic, but if you want to just change the options, then create 2 sets of them, and hide one while the other is active and vice versa.  See my edit for clarification.

Comment: Thank you for that.  It's exactly what I'm doing at the moment (unsemantic works in the same way that you've described), so I'll leave it at that for now.  Didn't know whether I was creating an unnecessary overhead by polling Facebook twice on every page load, since the breakpoints might never be triggered on most devices.